# Nested array .map without looping the parent array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

EXAMPLE: https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/a0ez5sy9/1/

I've created a JSON object called ProjectAPI.

```
  const ProjectAPI = {
      projects: [
        { 
          name: "PROJECT NAME", 
          thumbnail: "imageURL",
          image: [
            "imageURL",
            "imageURL",
            "imageURL" 
          ]
        },{ 
          name: "PROJECT NAME", 
          thumbnail: "imageURL",
          image: [
            "imageURL",
            "imageURL",
            "imageURL" 
          ]
        }],
  all: function() { return this.projects},
  get: function(id) {
    const isProject = p => p.number === id
    return this.projects.find(isProject)
  }
    }
```

Then I use .map to get the nested images:

```
 {
        ProjectAPI.all().map(function(item, index) {
          return <img className="img" key={index} src={item.image[index]} />
        })
      }
```

But is seems to loop through the parent array, so I end up with 6 images instead of 3 (in the jsfiddle example border red)

How can i just target the nested images?

Comment: `so I end up with 6 images instead of 3` do you mean `3 images instead of 6`?

Comment: Yes 3 images instead of 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since image is again an array so you need to run map on that also.

write it like this:

```
{
    ProjectAPI.all().map((item, index) => {
        return item.image.map((el,j) => <img className="img" key={j} src={el} />)
    })
}
```

**Update:**

You want the first three images of first object so you don't need to use nested map, write it like this:

```
ProjectAPI.all()[0].image.map((el,i) => <img className="img" key={i} src={el} />)
```

**[Fiddle with all the images](https://jsfiddle.net/rqzt4u9z/)**.

**[Fiddle with only three images](https://jsfiddle.net/LrxLck9p/)**.

Comment: maybe item.image.map ?

Comment: @Jonasw sorry my mistake, updated the answer thanks :)

Comment: How about if I only want to get the first 3 images only, now it gets all the images

Comment: first three images of first object of `projects` array ?

Comment: yes as each object will be a different page in my application

Comment: @user1177860 check the updated answer, let me know if this is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
src={item.image[index]}
```

`index` is the index within the `projects` array, it goes from `0..n`, where `n` is the number of objects in the `projects` array. For the forth item, you're trying to output `projects[3].image[3]`, which is nothing if that image array only holds three images.

If you want to output all three images of every project, you need to loop over the individual images as well.

Answer (score 0):

need to specify index of image url in image object. because in map function of your code specify the increment number 0 to 5 (length of your data).but your image array doesn't have value of index from map function.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
     {
        ProjectAPI.all().map(function(item, index) {
          return <img className="img" key={index} src={item.image[0]} />
        })
      }
    </div>
    );
  }
});
```